# MKAnnotation not showing callout on MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, automatic-ref-counting

I've got a `MKMapView` and I'm adding annotations like this:

```
for (NSDictionary *tmp in response)
{
    NSDictionary *places = [tmp objectForKey:@"place"];
    NSDictionary *location = [places objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSLog(@"long: %@ Lat:%@",[location objectForKey:@"longitude"], [location objectForKey:@"latitude"]);

    float longitude = [[location objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];
    float latitude = [[location objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationco = {latitude,longitude};
    NSString *titleString = [tmp objectForKey:@"name"];

    Place *pin = [[Place alloc] init];
    pin.coordinate = locationco;
    pin.title = titleString;
    pin.subtitle = @"A Location";

    //NSArray *annots = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:pin, nil];
    //[map addAnnotations:annots];
    [map addAnnotation:pin];
    [[map viewForAnnotation:pin] setCanShowCallout:YES];
}
```

The `MKAnnotation`'s show up on the map fine, and I can select them, however no callout bubble appears. I know that they are being selected properly form this

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [view setCanShowCallout:YES];
    NSLog(@"Title:%@",[view.annotation description]);
}
```

But that just prints out

```
Title:(null)
```

I'm using ARC, and I've got the properties set up in my Place object as such:

```
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, copy) NSString *subtitle;
```

What am I doing wrong/missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Before the `addAnnotation` line, can you NSLog `pin.title` and see what it shows?  Also, in the Place object did you override the `description` method by any chance and if so what code is in there?

Comment: The `NSLog(@"%@",pin.title);` Just returns `(null)`. I don't understand why though.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The callout doesn't show because the `title` is `nil`.

It is not necessary to implement `viewForAnnotation` to show callouts since the default map view implementation shows callouts.  (However, if you *do* implement it, you must set `canShowCallout` in that delegate method and not where you are doing it right now.)

Even if you set `canShowCallout` to `YES`, the callout still won't show if the `title` is `nil` or blank.

Log the `tmp` dictionary.  Either the `name` key is blank or it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Anna: there is no property tiltile for MKPinAnnotationView. how can i do the same.

Comment: This was the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 9):

You need to implement MKMapViewDelegate method `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`, which creates the view and returns it. In that method call `[view setCanShowCallout:YES];` on the view you plan to return for the annotation.

Because the `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` is called AFTER the pin has been selected it won't have any effect on enabling/disabling the callout.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing that code. Unfortunately I'm still having the problem. It appears the `pin.title` isn't being set properly, as if I try to print it just after setting it, it just prings `(null)`

Comment: Sorry, totally overlook that, you should accept the other answer as it's absolutely correct. :)